# Missing blanck line between directive and entries error

Tags: python-sphinx, toctree

I have just created my documentation using Sphinx and this is my problem:
Initially in the Toc tree directive is empty and then I add "tutorial" below and it looks like this:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
    tutorial
```

and when I "make html", I do not get "tutorial" on the index page. Then I created a tutorial.rst in the same dircetory as index.rst. I do "make html"again and I get this error message:

> toctree contains reference to nonexisting document

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe try this :

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   tutorial <tutorial>

..
```

Assuming your tutorial.rst file is in the "source" directory at the same level of your index.rst file

NOTE: newline is important between toctree options and page list.

Comment: This works. Is the official documentation (http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/toctree.html#toctree-directive) wrong?

Answer (score -2):

You have to have an empty line between the maxdepth definition and the filename.